# Stata: how to duplicate observations under certain conditions

Tags: stata

Please help me duplicate a variable under certain conditions? My original dataset looks like this:

```
week   category   averageprice

 1         1            5
 1         2            6
 2         1            4 
 2         2            7
```

This table says that for each week, there is a unique average price for each category of goods.

I need to create the following variables:

averageprice1 (av. price for category 1)

averageprice2 (av. price for category 2)

such that:

```
week     category  averageprice1  averageprice2

  1          1           5              6
  1          2           5              6
  2          1           4              7
  2          2           4              7
```

meaning that for week 1, average price for category 1 stayed at $5, and av. price for cater 2 stayed at 6. Similar logic applies to week 2. 
As you could see that the new variables are duplicated depending on a week.

I am still learning Stata. I tried:

> bysort week: replace averageprice1=averageprice if categ==1

but it doesn't work as  expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not duplicating observations (meaning here in the Stata sense, i.e. cases or records) here at all, as (1) the number of observations remains the same (2) you are copying certain values, not the contents of observations. Similar comment on "duplicating variables". However, that's just loose use of terminology.

Taking your example very literally

```
clear
input week   category   averageprice
1         1            5
1         2            6
2         1            4 
2         2            7
end 
bysort week (category) : gen averageprice1 = averageprice[1] 
by week: gen averageprice2 = averageprice[2] 
l

      +--------------------------------------------------+
      | week   category   averag~e   averag~1   averag~2 |
      |--------------------------------------------------|
   1. |    1          1          5          5          6 |
   2. |    1          2          6          5          6 |
   3. |    2          1          4          4          7 |
   4. |    2          2          7          4          7 |
      +--------------------------------------------------+
```

This is a standard application of subscripting with `by:`. Your code didn't work because it did not oblige Stata to look in other observations when that is needed. In fact your use of `bysort week` did not affect how the code applied at all.

EDIT:

A generalization is

```
egen averageprice1 = mean(averageprice / (category == 1)), by(week) 
egen averageprice2 = mean(averageprice / (category == 2)), by(week)
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. How does > bysort week (category) : gen averageprice1 = averageprice[1] is different from >
by week: gen averageprice2 = averageprice[2] ?

Comment: I tried running this but the first and the second codes produce same results.

Comment: Not so; I added the listing to make explicit that my code reproduces what you asked for. As for explanation, this is standard stuff. Please study manual entries e.g. [U] 13.7.2.

Comment: Thanks! This is very useful. I tried running the same code with this example and it worked exactly as you described. I am just uncertain why a variation of this code doesn't work with a different - slightly larger - dataset. The two codes generate same results as I mentioned earlier.

Comment: Why you get puzzling results with code you changed and datasets we can't see really is difficult to diagnose. One help forum insists on "commented, minimal, self-contained, reproducible code". That would be a good idea here too.

Comment: Nick! I found what the problem is. Even though my data looks like the example above, categories sometimes duplicate each other so in one particular week, we would could have two "category 1"s. Stata doesn't see that it is still category 1, and that it must ignore it. It treats the second "category 1" as "category 2" and duplicates its accordingly. Consequentially, it treats the third observation of "category 2" as category 3, etc. Is there a fix to it? Thanks. Even though information provided in duplicated categories is identical, I still need to keep them.

Comment: Is it possible to maybe used a separate (collapsed) table as a reference and ask Stata to match categories and average price values from there?

Comment: See EDIT for a suggestion.

Comment: It worked well. This is an incredible help. I greatly appreciate it.